# Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: ant, utf-8, maven, facelets, myfaces

I have a MyFaces Facelets application, where the page coding is a bit rugged. Anyway, it's developed with Eclipse and built with Ant, and kindof runs ok in Tomcat 2.0.26. So far so good.

Now, I'd rather build with Maven, so I made a couple of pom-files, opened them in Netbeans and built, and now I have a war file that deploys ok. However, on any facelet page it barfs out with

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:684)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:554)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1742)
```

So, I've tried a lot of different things, and the application actually run simple pages without facelet stuff. But, everything runs if I just build with Ant instead ... So my question is: What's the most likely difference between an ant build and a maven build that may cause this?

It also seems that even though I've configured for UTF-8 in Netbeans and pom-files, Netbeans eventually ends up reporting the facelet files as ISO-8859-1 after some editing.

I've made sure that most central libs are of same version (especially xerces 2.3.0), I've added an encoding servlet filter that had no effect.

And, I'd rather fix the maven build and keep the buggy pages, than the other way around ... it's my intention to introduce Naven, not fix buggy pages.

Here is what the pom.xml says about encoding:

Basically the pom.xml has the following set ...

```
 <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

....

    <properties>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>Tomcat60</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>utf-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
```

Comment: *It also seems that even though I've configured for UTF-8 in Netbeans and pom-files* Can you show what you did in the pom?

Comment: Looks good. However, without "seeing the whole", it seems hard to say anything. Just in case, have a look at http://72.5.124.102/thread.jspa?messageID=10633886.

Comment: I can't post the entire app, sorry. Any part, though ... and I've tried to check in an hex editor and "<" is represented as 3C XX where XX != 00, which indicates utf-8 I think.

Answer (score 3):

> com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.

The cause of this is a file that is not [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is being parsed as UTF-8. It is likely that the parser is encountering a byte value in the range `FE`-`FF`. These values are invalid in the UTF-8 encoding.

*The problem could probably be solved by changing the XML declaration of the file to be the correct encoding or re-encoding the file to UTF-8.*

Comment: I have the same issue - when opening the xml file in notepad++ it says the file is encoded in "UTF-8 without BOM". I tried converting (using notepad++) the file to "UTF-8" as well - the error message remains all the same. My xml declaration is: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> so as I see it, the encoding matches the declaration and still the above given error appears? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows it's very easy.  Get Notepad++ if you don't have it, and change the encoding using the "encoding" menu.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem!

I had solved it using the following piece of code:

```
String str = new String(oldstring.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. This encodes a string of dubious validity to UTF-8 bytes, then decodes them using the system encoding. Depending on the machine you run this code on, this operation may corrupt data or do absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when running some unit tests using maven on a Windows machine.

Files were being written out in the default `Windows-1252` format and then some tests were failing when trying to read them as `UTF-8`.

The solution was to enforce project source encoding for files being written out in the unit tests:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
        <configuration>
            <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=${project.build.sourceEncoding}</argLine>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

Where `project.build.sourceEncoding` was defined in the pom properties:

```
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
```